# Null check Operator used on a null value. Can't figure out how to not display an image if _pickedImage is null

Tags: flutter, image, file

Currently my app returns a null check error when attempting to load the login/sign up screen because the background image of the circle avatar returns null.

```
 // ignore_for_file: unnecessary_null_comparison

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class UserImagePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserImagePickerState createState() => _UserImagePickerState();
}

class _UserImagePickerState extends State<UserImagePicker> {
  File? _pickedImage;

  void _pickImage() async {
    final pickedImageFile =
        await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _pickedImage = pickedImageFile;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 50,
          backgroundImage: _pickImage != null ? FileImage(_pickedImage!) : null,
        ),
        TextButton.icon(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
            onPressed: _pickImage,
            icon: Icon(Icons.image),
            label: Text('Add Image')),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I would like for the circle avatar's background to be empty/null (meaning no image) on app start and would only display an image after the user takes a picture with the device camera.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
_pickImage != null
```

to

```
_pickedImage != null
```

You are checking the wrong variable

Comment: like this?

`backgroundImage: _pickImaged != null ? FileImage(_pickedImage!) : null,`

it returns an error saying _pickImaged isn't defined

Comment: @PlacidoPenitente i meant to say _pickedImage of course. sorry I wrote it wrong